# Check if row is filtered UiGrid

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have to check if a row is visible. This means if it's filtered  while looping insied the data.

```
$scope.col.grid.appScope.gridOptions.data.forEach(function (row) {
    //check if row is filtered
});
```

Any idea how can I do it ?

Comment: Please provide more code and add your view / ng-repeat.

Comment: hmm this is getting me the whole row , and i'm calling the grid like : 
<div id="gridFamily" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellnav ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-pagination class="grid blackBackground" style="height: 500px;"></div> and there is no filter or visible option ;s

Comment: you can get list of the visible rows using `$scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows` function and see if the row you're looking for is in there.